# Javascript to check if no valid scheme in url

Tags: javascript, validation, url-scheme

I need to make sure that urls without a valid scheme are caught and an `http://` added in front of them.

I know I could search for `http://` in the variable. But it would be better practice if there was some facility to check for a valid scheme properly. Is there a way to check for valid schemes?

```
var a = "www.example.com";
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is complicated and necessarily involves some guesswork, since what you've shown there is a valid *relative* URL. Are you able to assume that you're not dealing with relative URLs?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately for my application I need the http or https or whatever scheme it is....

Comment: "Yes" meaning "Yes, I know they're not relative URLs"?

Comment: www.example.com wouldn't be valid :)

Comment: `www.example.com` is a perfectly valid relative URL. It's a simple question: Do you need to allow for relative URLs, or not? If you're scraping web pages, the answer would normally be "Yes, I need to allow for them."

Comment: Ok, now I understand.....no my script detects internal urls....."No, I do not need to allow for them"......sorry I can be a ditzzz sometimes

Comment: :-) Just as long as you're aware that not all relative links are *internal*. For instance, on `http://example.com/index.html`, this is a perfectly valid link to Stack Overflow: `<a href="//stackoverflow.com">...</a>`. More in [this post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/skipping-protocol.html) on my anemic little blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is complicated by the fact that what you've shown is a perfectly valid *relative* URL. Differentiating relative URLs from broken absolute URLs necessarily involves some guesswork.

If you know you're **not dealing with relative URLs**, then by definition we're dealing with links that should have a scheme, and so we can look for ones that don't. If we refer to [RFC-3986 §3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) we see that the scheme is separated from the rest of the URL by a `:`:

```
The following are two example URIs and their component parts:

         foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
         \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
          |           |            |            |        |
       scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
          |   _____________________|__
         / \ /                        \
         urn:example:animal:ferret:nose
```

...and from [§3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1), we can see that schemes are a series of an alpha followed by zero or more alphanums, `+`, `-`, or `.`, seprated from the rest of the URL by a `://`:

```
scheme      = ALPHA *( ALPHA / DIGIT / "+" / "-" / "." )
```

So you can tell with a simple regular expression:

```
if (!/^[a-z][a-z0-9+.\-]*:/i.test(a)) {
    // 'a' doesn't start with a scheme
}
```

But again, only if you're not dealing with relative URLs.

That regex says:

- `^` - start of input
- `[a-z]` - any alpha char as normally defined in RFCs (e.g., English letters A through Z)
- `[a-z0-9+.\-]*` - zero or more (that's the `*` at the end) of any alpha, digit, `+`, `.`, or `-`.
- `:` - a colon

...and the `i` flag means "case-insensitive."

Comment: Ah wow I wasn't aware of RFC-3986 §3.....so there's no built in function but there is a pattern of :// that can be detected.....

Comment: @AmyNeville: Sorry, I mislead there, let me fix it.

Comment: @AmyNeville: Fixed it now. The `hier-part` doesn't have to start with `//` for all schemes, so it's just the colon.

Comment: Just testing it right now on my application but when the timer lets me I'll accept if it works :)